# How do I update a branch taken from my local repository in git?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Apologies if it is a duplicate question. I am a newbie to git from perforce and the terminologies are a bit confusing.

I have done something like below.

I have cloned a local repository(say folder named MASTER) from remote branch called master.

From this, I have created a branch XYZ using `git checkout master`;`git branch XYZ` and `git-new-workdir` commands.

Now I updated the local repository (the folder MASTER) using `git pull` to get the recent changes.

I would like to propagate this to my branch XYZ which was taken from my local repository.

How do I do this ? Again use a `git pull` ?

If I try `git pull`, it says "There is no tracking information for the current branch."

So what do I do ?

Comment: i think you want to `push` http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: No i am not trying to push the changes to upstream. I am trying to propagate it to a local branch which got forked of my local repository.

Comment: in the first place: don't name your folder or project ```master``` it's confusing for us to understand when you're talking about your working copy or the master branch. In second place, I understand you made a branch ```XYZ``` from ```master```, then added some changes to ```master```. You want XYZ to have these changes as well, right?

Comment: `git checkout oldbranch` && `git merge newbranch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to `rebase` your branch onto master.

#### Rebase vs Merge

Let's assume your history looks like this after pulling:

```
      c---d---e <- Your branch
     /
a---b---f---g---h <- master (after the pull)
```

#### Rebase

When using `rebase` ([documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)) your commit graph would look like this:

```
                  c'---d'---e' <- Your branch
                 /
a---b---f---g---h <- master
```

The command you need to use is `git rebase master <your-branch>` but make sure that your working directory is clean. If you have uncommited changes you should save them via `git stash`.

#### Merge

If you use `merge` ([documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)) it would look like this, with `i` being the merge commit.

```
      c---d---e---i <- Your branch
     /           /
a---b---f---g---h <- master
```

#### Advantage of rebasing

The difference between a `merge` and a `rebase` is that `merge` will create a single commit in your branch which contains all the changes you pulled from the server. Using rebase you put your own commits on top of the pulled commits.

When doing a rebase you can finish your work by doing a `fast-forward merge`, this would result in a clean linear history, which will make it more readable.

```
a---b---f---g---h---c'---d'---e' <- Your branch, master
```

The same wouldn't be possible if you merged before rather than to rebase.

---

For more information on the topic you can take a look at the [Git Branching - Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) from the [gitpro book](http://git-scm.com/book).

Comment: Thanks. Very well explained. Sorry, i could not upvote since i do not have enough reputation. 

I have tried a somewhat different method(essentially i believe it is same as your method) after i saw few other similar questions yesterday and it worked. 
`
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master XYZ 
and then
git pull --rebase.
`
This worked.

Comment: Your approach will result in the same history. With the rebase flag git will obviously use rebase to bring your branch up to date after pulling.

Comment: @ShankarNarayanan But be wary, by setting the upstream to `origin/master` any `git push` will push the changes of XYZ to the master branch of origin and not a XYZ pendant. Just for your interest.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Zeeker ! I typically do a git commit in the branch XYZ. go to the original MASTER local repository(which is the parent to XYZ), do a git pull --rebase and then cherry pick the commit made in XYZ. and then do a git commit and git push. I know this is a round about way of doing things, but it helps me in working on different issues in different branches.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried merging master into XYZ using `git checkout XYZ` and `git merge master`?

[Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

Comment: I think a rebase would be preferable